# Paginate results from a loop function in php

Tags: php

I have a function which checks for a parent child relationship in my database and continues until no relationship is found.

It works well. I just need to paginate it as sometimes the results can get quite large and take too long to load as well as become unreadable.

How can I make this so it only loads a certain number of results and then call it again so it picks up where it left off?

```
function display_children($parent, $level) {
  $result = checkChild($parent);

    if ($result['Count'] > 0) {
        foreach ($result['Items'] as $key => $item) {
            echo $level . $item;
            display_children($itemRepNum, $level+1);
        }
    }
}
```

The Database is structured in an adjacency list model with a structure like this:

```
Parent | Title
       | Car
Car    | Ford
Ford   | Fusion
Car    | Toyota
Toyota | Prius
Prius  | 4door
Ford   | F150
Car    | BMW
...
```

Comment: Which database type are you using? (assuming MySQL) It would probably be best to use a [LIMIT](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp) in your query. E.g. `$itemspp=30; $page=5; $query = $sql->prepare("SELECT * FROM 'table' LIMIT ?,?"); $query->bind_params('ii', $page*$itemspp, $page); ` and so on.

Comment: limit won't work because each child depends on a parent so queries are all singe

Comment: Add a limit in checkChild if `$level == 0`?